# How to use class variables inside constructor in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Why am I not able to access variables inside the constructor?

```js
class Dir {
  refs = {};

  constructor(dir, label, reverse, clockwise) {
    this.dir = dir;

    // error: refs is not defined
    Dir.prototype.refs[label] = { ref: this, reverse, clockwise };
    // this wont work either
    Dir.refs[label] = { ref: this, reverse, clockwise };
  }
}

// test
const dirU = new Dir([0, -1], 'U', 'D', 'R');
```

`refs` is accessible outside the constuctor:

```js
class Dir {
  refs = {};
  constructor(dir, label, reverse, clockwise) {
    this.dir = dir;
  }
}
const dirU = new Dir([0, -1], 'U', 'D', 'R');
console.log(dirU.refs);
// will print '{}'
```

This will solve it, but it is much less convient:

```js
class Dir {
  constructor(dir, label, reverse, clockwise) {
    this.dir = dir;
    if (!(label in Dir.prototype)) Dir.prototype.refs = {};
    Dir.prototype.refs[label] = { ref: this, reverse, clockwise };
  }
}
```

How can I access class variable inside the constructor? Is this even possible in javascript?

clarification:i want `refs` to remember all previous instances with a dictionary of labels.
I want the Dir class to hold a dictionary of all of his instances. in python this is how you would write it, but in javascript it doesn't work.

Comment: `Dir.prototype.refs[label]` -> `this.refs[label]`. If you want to interact with the instance, it's just `this`. You're not interacting with the prototype or statically with the class.

Comment: no, i want `refs` to remember all previous instances with a dictionary of labels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `refs` static. Then use `Dir.refs`. That is:

```js
class Dir {
  static refs = {};

  constructor(dir, label, reverse, clockwise) {
    this.dir = dir;
    Dir.refs[label] = { ref: this, reverse, clockwise };
  }
}
```

Comment: great! thanks! will accept it in 3 minutes.

Comment: @EliavLouski ... how about the concern you were raising in your Q. of not exposing the references into public? ... *"... `refs` is accessible outside the constructor  ..."*. This above provided approach does not prevent it. The only approach which does fully cover this requirement was to use additional encapsulation.

Comment: @PeterSeliger actually, I want it to be accessible publicly